# How to Display a menu only if it has Posts in Custom Menu?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus

I created a custom taxonomy as category and display it by wp_nav_menu. The problem is, so far there are some terms in the custom taxonomy has no post attached to it, but it still show in the menu. So when people click on the menu link, they  will got to a Nothing Found page.

How do I display the menu/term that only has post in it in  wp_nav_menu?

Comment: If you've tried some code already (even if it doesn't work, but is logical) add it to your question.

Comment: nope, i just add `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'custom_tax', 'menu_class' => '', 'container' => 'catmenu','items_wrap' => '%3$s') ); ?>` in my theme,I couldn't found any hook for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figure it out.

Instead of using wp_nav_menu, I use wp_list_categories which has more parameters that we can control. 
So to not display empty menu, I use:

```
<?php  wp_list_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'custom_tax','hide_empty' => '1','title_li' => '')); ?>
```

the `hide_empty` do the magic here.